# Replace all XX attributes to numeric ID with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to clone a `div` element by clicking on an `a` element. And when that `div` cloned, all **XX** attributes change to it's numeric ID.
For example:

- `for="gr_name_XX"` to `for="gr_name_1"`
- `name="grfield[XX][name]"` to `name="grfield[1][name]"`
- `id="gr_name_XX"` to `id="gr_name_1"`

I'm trying to do that, but only the `div` element's ID attribute doing this function and change to numeric ID. Sorry, I'm novice in javascript and jQuery coding. It's my code:

```js
var elementCounter = 0;

jQuery(document).ready(function() {

  jQuery("#add-new-game").click(function() {
    var elementRow = jQuery("#placeholder-item").clone();
    var newId = "gr-item-" + elementCounter;

    elementRow.attr("id", newId);
    elementRow.show();

    // Where I have problem!!
    elementRow.each(function() {
      elementRow.html().replace(/XX/g, elementCounter);
    });

    var removeLink = jQuery("a", elementRow).click(function() {
      removeElement(elementRow);
      return false;
    });

    elementCounter++;
    jQuery("input[name=element-max-id]").val(elementCounter);

    jQuery(".add-and-remove-items").append(elementRow);

    return false;
  });

});

function removeElement(element) {
  jQuery(element).remove();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="sortable-items add-and-remove-items settings-items gr-items"></div>

<input type="hidden" name="element-max-id" />
<a href="#" id="add-new-game">Add new</a>

<div class="sortable-item add-and-remove-item settings-item gr-item front-page-element" id="placeholder-item" style="display: none;">
  <label for="gr_name_XX" style="width: 90px; display: inline-block;">Name: </label>
  <input type="text" name="grfield[XX][name]" class="regular-text" id="gr_name_XX" value="" />
  <label for="gr_genre_XX" style="width: 90px; display: inline-block;">Genre: </label>
  <input type="text" name="grfield[XX][genre]" class="regular-text" id="gr_genre_XX" value="" />
  <br>
  <label for="gr_backg_XX" style="width: 90px; display: inline-block;">Background: </label>
  <input type="text" name="grfield[XX][backg]" class="regular-text" id="gr_backg_XX" value="" />
  <label for="gr_date_XX" style="width: 90px; display: inline-block;">Date: </label>
  <input type="text" name="grfield[XX][date]" class="regular-text" id="gr_date_XX" value="" />
  <label for="gr_nc_XX"><input type="checkbox" name="grfield[XX][nc]" id="gr_nc_XX" value="1" /> String date</label>
  <a href="#">Remove</a><br>
</div>
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to use `each` and also `.html()` only returns the markup content. For updating, you need to do `.html(YOUR-UPDATE-CODE)`,

change,

```
// Where I have problem!!
elementRow.each(function() {
  elementRow.html().replace(/XX/g, elementCounter);
});
```

To

```
elementRow.html(elementRow.html().replace(/XX/g, elementCounter));
```

**Demo:**

```js
var elementCounter = 0;

jQuery(document).ready(function() {

  jQuery("#add-new-game").click(function() {
    var elementRow = jQuery("#placeholder-item").clone();
    var newId = "gr-item-" + elementCounter;

    elementRow.attr("id", newId);
    elementRow.show();

    elementRow.html(elementRow.html().replace(/XX/g, elementCounter));

    var removeLink = jQuery("a", elementRow).click(function() {
      removeElement(elementRow);
      return false;
    });

    elementCounter++;
    jQuery("input[name=element-max-id]").val(elementCounter);

    jQuery(".add-and-remove-items").append(elementRow);

    return false;
  });

});

function removeElement(element) {
  jQuery(element).remove();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="sortable-items add-and-remove-items settings-items gr-items"></div>

<input type="hidden" name="element-max-id" />
<a href="#" id="add-new-game">Add new</a>

<div class="sortable-item add-and-remove-item settings-item gr-item front-page-element" id="placeholder-item" style="display: none;">
  <label for="gr_name_XX" style="width: 90px; display: inline-block;">Name: </label>
  <input type="text" name="grfield[XX][name]" class="regular-text" id="gr_name_XX" value="" />
  <label for="gr_genre_XX" style="width: 90px; display: inline-block;">Genre: </label>
  <input type="text" name="grfield[XX][genre]" class="regular-text" id="gr_genre_XX" value="" />
  <br>
  <label for="gr_backg_XX" style="width: 90px; display: inline-block;">Background: </label>
  <input type="text" name="grfield[XX][backg]" class="regular-text" id="gr_backg_XX" value="" />
  <label for="gr_date_XX" style="width: 90px; display: inline-block;">Date: </label>
  <input type="text" name="grfield[XX][date]" class="regular-text" id="gr_date_XX" value="" />
  <label for="gr_nc_XX"><input type="checkbox" name="grfield[XX][nc]" id="gr_nc_XX" value="1" /> String date</label>
  <a href="#">Remove</a><br>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are going to do is first get and loop the children of your `elementRow` then loop through each attribute of that child:

```
  // get and loop through each children
  $(elementRow).children().each(function () {
     var child = $(this)[0];

     // loop through each attribute
     for (var i = 0; i < child.attributes.length; i++)
     {
        var attributeVal = child.attributes[i].value;

        // check if attribute value contains XX
        if (attributeVal.indexOf("XX") != -1)
        {
            // replace it
            child.attributes[i].value = attributeVal.replace(/XX/g, elementCounter)
        }
     }
  });
```

`$(this)[0]` is a way of getting the `original javascript HTML object reference` instead of getting `jQuery object`.

`.attributes` is a property of `JS HTML Object` and does not exist in `jQuery HTML object`.

[working fiddle based on your example](https://jsfiddle.net/qfek4eky/)

hope that helps.